# How do I get two dockerized applications to talk on a given port?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I'm trying to get two dockerized applications to speak to eachother on a given port according to my docker-compose.yml file.

They are able to speak to eachother on port app1:61001 and app2:61002, but my friend tells me that they should be able to communicate on port 80. example.. app2:80, and that port 61001 and 61002 should only be the accessible ports exposed out of the swarm.

The applications themselves are set to server.port=80

Any idea how I can get it working as my friend suggests?

Here is the docker-compose file I'm using:

docker compose

```
version: "3.5" 

services: 
  app1: 
    image: docker.artifactory.gr.gr.com/app1:latest 
    ports: 
      - "61001:80" 
    deploy: 
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      - custom-network

  app2:
    image: docker.artifactory.gr.gr.com/app2:latest
    ports:
      - "61002:80"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      - custom-network

networks:
  custom-network:
```

My

Comment: Your friend is right, they should internally communicate via port 80, but I think you have to expose it in the `ports` list (ie add a `- 80` above the outside mapping).

Answer (score 1):

first, look if your service expose port 80 with `docker-compose ps` command.
If is in this case, juste remove folowing code of your both services

```
    ports:
      - "61002:80"
```

if not, remove

```
    ports:
      - "61002:80"
```

and add

```
    expose: 80
```

and in your app script, to call one service, just call appN:80

I hope i understood your request and i helped you

Answer (score -1):

App1 and App2 are part of the same network that you named custom-network.
This means that the internal port used by the containers ( the one on the right, 80 ) is  visible from both applications!
If you have to call a service from APP 1 to APP 2 you simply have to name the container with

```
hostname: app2 // do the same for the other container
container_name: app2
```

Then, from app1, you can call the application simply using "app1:80/yourpath".
The port exposed are visible OUTSIDE the network.

In addition:
You can check the connectivity, connecting into app1 application with an iterative shell:https://gist.github.com/mitchwongho/11266726 and then executing

```
ping app1
```

you will see that app1 has an internal IP and that is reachable.

Comment: Neither `hostname` nor `container_name:` are necessary for inter-container communication; Compose will make the names of the service blocks available as DNS names.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details.

Comment: yes but in this case the name will be automatically assigned by docker, or not?

Comment: In the `docker-compose.yml` file in the original question, `app1` and `app2` will be valid DNS names the containers can use to contact each other.  Compose will also assign a container name, but you don't generally need that for anything.

Comment: ok, it's true; I missed that. The ability to read slowly and well is very underestimated. tnx